# OpenCL calling the same kernel many times

Tags: java, c++, opencl, gpu

I am using JavaCL API and I need to perform operation where one kernel need to be launched many times. In order to depict the principle I have written the algorithm:

```
for(int k = 0; k < n; k++){
    CLEvent calculation = kernels.calculation(queue, d_in2, d_in1, d_out, n, k, new int[] {n,n}, null);
    (wait till the end of the "calculation" kernel)
    (take d_out and give as an input to "calculation" kernel)
    (launch calculation kernel again)
}
```

Before launching the next "calculation" kernel, the first one should wait till the end of the first kernel and the results from the first kernel need to be passed to next one.

How to implement this algorithm in host code of JavaCL? **I think that example with any OpenCl API as well as OpenCL host code in C++ would be helpful.**

Answer (score 0):

OpenCL is based on a queue. Say you've got a queue, and you put 3 kernels into it, A, B, C. B will *not* execute before A has finished, guaranteed (unless you specifically ask for an out of order command queue), and neither will C execute before B has finished.

This means if you've got 2 buffers, in and out, you can simply do something like this (pseudocode)

```
for(int i=0; i<iterations/2; i++)
{
    clSetKernelArg(kernelA, 0, in)
    clSetKernelArg(kernelA, 1, out)
    launchkernelA

    clSetKernelArg(kernelA, 1, in)
    clSetKernelArg(kernelA, 0, out)
    launchkernelA
}
```

This will ping pong the data between the two buffers, ensuring that each kernel is launched with the output to the previous kernel launch as its input

In your case it looks like your data is a little more complex than that, but the principle still applies